# Upper div Linear Algebra

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a quick question on linear algebra!

Consider this: 
$$
(3,-2,0) +(-1,1,4)= (2,-1,4).$$ Thus, $\mathbb R^3$ is a vector space over $\mathbb R$ (field of real numbers).

Does this sentence mean that since you started off with two, 3 dimensional vectors, and after adding them together, your answer is still a 3 dimensional vector, that means that it's still in the same vector space?

Thank you.

Comment: There are a few more axioms than that... but closure is a requirement of vector spaces.

Answer (score 1):

From this little example it does clearly not follows, that $\mathbb{R}^3$ is a vector space. Maybe you want to have a look [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space) at the definition of a vector-space. It would be a good exercise for you to verify, that $\mathbb{R}^3$ satisfies the axioms and is therefore a vector space over the real numbers.